# Why were they going to kill the female protagonist in Equals?

Tags: equals

In the movie "Equals" the female protagonist was self-diagnosed as having SOS.

Individuals with SOS were eventually put to death in the DEN after long treatments, however at one point in the movie a cure was finally found.

The woman saw her doctor and expected to be diagnosed with SOS. Instead she was told that she was pregnant. She was immediately taken to the DEN and it appeared they were killing her in a gas chamber when she was rescued.

This begs multiple questions, which I will boil down to:

1. Why did they take her to the DEN if she was only diagnosed as being pregnant?
2. Why was killing and suicide still going on at the DEN after they had the cure?

Comment: I don’t think the [tag:plot]  tag is necessary, for rather the same reasons we don’t have a [tag:science-fiction] tag. The vast majority of questions on this site are about the plot of a work, in one way or another.

Comment: See also [this](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3563/should-we-delete-plot-explanation-tag) meta post.

Comment: @Adamant Sorry, I thought there was already a plot tag. I was thinking of another SE site; TV SE I think.